# Copy and move a file in git?

Tags: git

What is the command to simply make a copy of a folder or file and then move it over to another folder in git? I know `mv` allows you "cut and paste" files from one folder to another.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rename (=move) an existing file in git, you can use `git mv <old path> <new path>`.

Git has no special way of copying a file - just copy it as you would copy any other file (e.g., use the `cp` command if you're using a unix-like OS), and then commit the newly created file.

Comment: The implication being that you won't have a history for the new file.